# Faster alternative for find and sort in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, find

I am working on community detection with a genetic algorithm. Communities are represented in locus-based representation, that each index(gene) and it's value are in same community.

For example in the figure below, if the chromosome is (b) the communities will be (d)

[image: locus-based representation]

So to extract communities from a chromosome, I need to iteratively find the indexes and values, to do this, I have written this code:

```
while (SumComms)~=nVar
    j=find(Sol>0,1,'first');%find the first node which has not placed in any community
    Com=[j,Sol(j)];%index of the node and it's value
    Comsize=0;
    while Comsize<numel(Com)
        Comsize=numel(Com);
        x=find(ismembc(Sol,sort([Com,Sol(Com)])));%Indexes which Com occure in Sol
        Com=unique([Com,x,Sol(x)]);
    end
    Sol(Com)=0;
    i=i+1;
    SumComms=SumComms+numel(Com);
    Communities{i}=Com;
end
```

But `x=find(ismembc(Sol,sort([Com,Sol(Com)])))` is very time consuming in even mid-size networks. Do you know any faster way?

Comment: Yes, your image is displayed for me.

Comment: Provide a sample of what `SumComms`, `nVar`, and `Sol` are in the beginning and provide and explain what  the output will be for those variables

Comment: `SumCumms` is number of clustered nodes and `nVar` is total number of nodes, so termination condition is `while (SumComms)~=nVar`, in the other words, until all of the node has placed in a community the loop wil run. `Sol` is the choromosome

Comment: for example in the image, `Sol` is Genotype, `nVar` is 9 (0 to 8). and `SumComms` grows in the loop until 9,(`nVar`)

Comment: @SardarUsama, an array of numbers.(which represents genes)

Comment: I did as much as i could,  i think the Question, Pic and Comments are informative enough. I agree that it is a bit complicated.

Comment: As far as I understand,  you have these variables at the beginning `SumComms=0;` `Sol=[3,0,3,1,5,6,4,7,7];` `nVar=0:8;` , and for this, your code executes in nearly `0.0005` seconds for me. Not sure how you find it slow. If that's not correct,  you should add a sample of those variables then everything will be clear. That pic is of no use for this site.

Comment: @SardarUsama thanks for trying to help. your sample data are correct. but in my real network `nVar=500000` and this line take about 399 second (about quarter of whole program). i think its time exponentially grows with size of `nVar`, so i need a faster way..

Comment: `ismembc` even with `sort` is too faster than `ismember`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using logical vector. Instead of operation on indices we can define `Com` as a logical vector so operations on indices such as `ismember` can be reduced to indexing operations:

```
i=0;
SumComms=0;
nVar = 9;
Sol = [3 0 3 1 5 6 4 7 7]+1;
while SumComms ~= nVar
    j=find(Sol>1,1,'first');
    Com = false(1,nVar);
    Com([j Sol(j)])=true;
    Comsize=0;
    sumcom = 2;
    while Comsize<sumcom
        Comsize=sum(Com);
        Com(Sol(Com))=true;
        Com = Com(Sol);
        Com(Sol(Com))=true;
        sumcom = sum(Com);
    end
    Sol(Com)=1;
    i = i + 1;
    SumComms=SumComms+sumcom;
    Communities{i}=find(Com);
end
```

Result of a test in Octave shows that the proposed method is at least 10x faster than the original method .

Comment: thank you for your solution, but i tested this and my function run about 10 percent faster, how you run 10x faster? i am using matlab 2017a, you think Octave is such faster?

Comment: one more thing, in my data some nodes can be null, their value is -1, my code works with that, how do i change your code to handle negative values? for example: `Sol = [3 0 3 1 5 6 4 7 7 -1]`

Comment: I tested it with random data for example `nVar  = 1000;Sol = randi(nVar,1,nVar);` . You may upload your data so we can test. Usually MATLAB is faster than Octave.

Comment: You should add `1` to the values `Sol = [3 0 3 1 5 6 4 7 7 -1]+1` and here null values will be `0`. Consider to change these parts of your function:     `j=find(Sol>1,1,'first');` and `Sol(Com)=1;`.

Comment: Here is an [online Octave test](http://rextester.com/IOI40361). You can see that my method is nearly 7x faster. I used `ismember` because Octave doesn't have `ismembc`. You can test both methods and use `isequal` to see if results of methods are equal.

Comment: your code works for special cases, for example if `Sol=[1,3,4,5,2]` and you add `1` then it wont work. also for `Sol=[1,3,4,2,-1]`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. In the answer it is assumed that min of Sol is `1` if min of  your original data is already `1` you don't need to increment the data.